# Volume Scattering in 2.8 Doesn't work?

Tags: volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

Volume scatter not working in 2.8 build for the Mac? I tried plugging in the volume scatter node to the world output and checked the volumetric box. But nothing happens in Eevee! Please help.

Comment: did you connect the volume scatter node to the VOLUME input on the world output node?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to check "Volumetric" under the render settings on the right.[image]